# A minimization problem involving a hypersurface

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, optimization

Let $\mathbf{z}=(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ be a point in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Assume that $z_j=x_j+\iota 
y_j$. Let $d\ge 3$.

We want to maximize $\dfrac{x_2}{\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{x_3}{\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{x_4}{\sqrt{3}}$

such that $\begin{align} & \sum_{j=1}^n z_j^d=0, \\ & \sum_{j=1}^n|z_j|^2=1.
\end{align}$

I tried to set up an Euler-Lagrange equation but the main problem while solving this optimization problem is the first constraint. Is there any way to solve this type of problem, in particular this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the first constraint?

Comment: There is no problem, but while solving via the Euler Lagrange method I am getting a degree $d-1$ equation which I am unable to solve.

Comment: The first constraint is more like two constraints, isn't it? Both the real and imaginary parts of $\sum_j z_j^d$ must be zero.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes.